# Does description-file in setup.cfg, section "metadata" have any effect?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I recently downloaded 208,492 of Python packages from PyPI. 18,844 of them had a `setup.cfg` with a `metadata` section which contained the key `description-file`. Does that key have any effect on setuptools or PyPI? It is mentioned in [the setuptools docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files), but I don't understand it.

### Example setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
name = foopackage
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not mentioned in the code, neither in `distutils` nor in `setuptools`:

```
distutils $ grep -Frw description-file .
distutils $ cd ../setuptools
setuptools $ grep -Frw description-file .
```

If you want to publish long description from a file via `setup.cfg` use

```
long_description = file: README.rst
```

trick. See [the very `setuptools`' `setup.cfg`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/54b76e63bb7ace4cd1be29d75f6dcfe3227444f9/setup.cfg#L23). It's handled in [`setuptools/config.py`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/54b76e63bb7ace4cd1be29d75f6dcfe3227444f9/setuptools/config.py#L271).

Comment: Some tutorials say that the content of this file is shown on PyPI. But this does not seem to be the case and setting it is probably just a cargo cult ritual. As phd already wrote, `long_description` is used instead, and `description-file` does not appear in distutils or setuptools. Neither can I find it in the source code of the current and legacy PyPI versions.

Comment: The `description-file` key is specific to [pbr (Python Build Reasonableness)](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html) – which ironically invented an unreasonable new key rather than reusing the existing `long_description = file: ...` syntax described above. This is why we can't have nice things, folks.

Comment: @CecilCurry Do you want to make this comment an answer?